# Norm of sine\cosine

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

In $L_2$ space we define norm as dot product on itself, for sinus it will be:
$$ ||\sin(x)|| = \left[\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(x)\sin(x)dx\right]^{1/2}$$

And after simple integrating we find that:

$$||\sin(x)|| = \sqrt{\pi}$$

so my question is:

in terms of Euklidian space we deem that norm it's a length\amplitude of vector, but what does it mean when we concern about functions, not vectors?

P.S. I hope i could explain my thoughts properly

Comment: Use $\sin$ as `\sin`

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Thx you for correcting, I will edit it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a rather strong extent, the answer is “it’s still the magnitude of the vector. You’re not just good ad visualizing Hilbert Spaces.” Your final sentence is wrong; $L^2$ is a vector space, and $\sin(x)$ is a vector inside of that vector space.

Comment: Thx for the prompt answer, but what kind of magnitude it is? From Fourier series theory I know, that we can use sine, and cosine as orthogonal basis for analysis of functions. And I always think about sine and cosine as some kind of unit vector's, and now I'm having some problem when trying to reconcile my understanding of unit vector's with fact that unit vector in $L_2$ have magnitude of $\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: @qqffx why do you call it the unit vector?

Comment: @qqffx Forming an orthogonal basis does not mean that they are unit vectors. $(2,0),(0,2)$ form an orthogonal basis despite not being unit vectors. In order to get *unit* basis vectors you need to divide by the length ($\sqrt{\pi}$).

Comment: Based on your comment, I think you are thinking about things correctly (generally), but may have some terminology wrong which is causing you confusion.

Comment: @StellaBiderman yes, right, sorry i was mistaken. And still is there some way to visualize that magnitude?

Comment: I’m not sure what “what kind of magnitude is it” is supposed to mean. You have a way of computing distance, you have a vector. $\sqrt{\pi}$ is how long the vector is according to that distance.

Comment: I'm think I get it, it's was straightforward translate from Russian, supposed to mean: what this magnitude will be mean on graph in case where we can plot such a graph ( I'm still thinking about visualization)  thanks again for patience, and sorry for my bad English)